# UUIDs & Search Engine Friendly URLs

Tags: url, seo, uuid

Our SaaS app, currently in beta, allows users to generate conversations.  A conversation's URL currently looks like this:

http://example.com/conversations/view/4c6a4ab4-4795-4a13-a3d9-d9d22cac28e5

I'd like to change the URL to something search engine friendly like this:

http://example.com/conversations/this-is-a-great-conversation-that-you-need-to-join

However, since conversation can potentially have the same title, we'll need the conversation's ID in there.  But, that would give us a really nasty looking URL:

http://example.com/conversations/this-is-a-great-conversation-that-you-need-to-join/4c6a4ab4-4795-4a13-a3d9-d9d22cac28e5

Does anyone have any ideas on how to include a smaller unique ID in the URL so that we don't have to include the UUID?

Answer (score 1):

believe me, it's not seo friendly at all:

http://example.com/conversations/this-is-a-great-conversation-that-you-need-to-join

it's more spammy than seo friendly url. since google reduced value of keywords in url

http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-on-keywords-in-the-url-16976

keywords in url should not be more that 4 or 5 keywords.

i think you should reduce you url size and depth levels. for instance:

http://example.com/c584501

can work for you. "c" in the beginning means "conversations" you can identify your url by a character without using more levels like:

http://example.com/conversations/584501

the shorter url the more chance of sharing it on social medias.

you can use id of your table in database or use uniqueId if you use php:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

i usually use my table id and i convert it to base36 with base_convert()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php